# getServerSideProps access current browser url

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am calling getServerSideProps and passing in the req and res parameters like this:

```
export async function getServerSideProps({ req, res }) {}
```

I need to get the current browser url path and I can't find it in the request object.
Is there a way to get the current url inside getServerSideProps?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use the `resolvedUrl` field from the context parameter.

```js
export async function getServerSideProps({ req, res, resolvedUrl }) {
    console.log(resolvedUrl)

   // Remaining code
}
```

From the [`getServerSideProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-server-side-props#context-parameter) documentation:

> `resolvedUrl`: A normalized version of the request URL that strips the
> `_next/data` prefix for client transitions and includes original query values.

Note that `resolvedUrl` will not return the domain part of the URL, only the path and query string are returned.

Comment: Just telling that this won't give you the request parameters. You'll only get /api in /api?name=john

Comment: In `getServerSideProps`, the `resolvedUrl` param includes the original query values of the URL.

Comment: So you're saying that in `/api?name=john`, resolvedUrl will give you `/api?name=john` and not `/api`. I haven't tested this in simple use case but i was using route rewrites in nextjs and resolvedUrl did not return any of the query paramters.

Comment: `/api` is an API route which is not handled by `getServerSideProps`. Using rewrites might influence what gets passed depending on how you've set it up.

Answer (score 3):

You can have access to domain name via headers object in incoming request

```
// localhost:3000
context.req.headers.host
```

If you want the rest of the path, you can have it in url property in incoming request object

```
//blog/3
context.req.url
```

Full example:

```
export function getServerSideProps (context){

    // localhost:3000
    const domain = context.req.headers.host

    // /blog/3
    const path = context.req.url

    //localhost:3000/blob/3
    const fullAddress = domain + path

}
```