# Next.js getServerSideProps | Strange behavior for a function

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Strange behavior for a function.
Sometimes the wrong address of the server request

```
console.log ({url: context.req.url})
```

and prints to the console

```
{url: '/_next/data/development/en-gb/b.json?culture=en-gb'}
```

and this breaks all the logic that is associated with the current request address.
Why is this happening and how to fix it

I am using functions wrapper for standard functions

```
export function getServerSidePropsWithPageInitData(options: PropsOptions = {}) {

  //redux-wrapper
  return wrapper.getServerSideProps((store) => {

    const { getState, dispatch } = store;

    return async function(context: GetServerSidePropsContext) {


      console.log({ url: context.req.url }) // {url: '/_next/data/development/en-gb/b.json?culture=en-gb'}
      
      return  await getPageInitialData(serverContext);

      // some logic and return object look like
      // { props: {key: value } }
      // or redirect
      // redirect: {
      //  permanent: false,
      //  destination: destination
      // }
    };
  })
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [getServerSideProps access current browser url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65617150/getserversideprops-access-current-browser-url)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `resolvedUrl` property:

> `resolvedUrl`: A normalized version of the request URL that strips the _next/data prefix for client transitions and includes original query values.

More: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering