# Next.js redirect to login page and redirect back

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

I need to redirect our users to a SSO form that is handle by another team. This form (is not a next.js app) is on the same domain as the next.js app.
I try to follow https://nextjs.org/docs/authentication#authenticating-server-rendered-pages but I can't figure out on how to get the current URL, so I can tell the SSO to redirect back once authentication is finish.

```
return {
  redirect: {
    destination: `/sso/form?redirect=${currentUrl}`,
    permanent: false,
  },
}
```

Any idea, on how to get the currentUrl?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [getServerSideProps access current browser url](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65617939/1870780)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context contain a property called `resolvedUrl` corresponding to the current route.

```
        const { resolvedUrl, req } = context;
        const baseUrl = getBaseUrl(req);
        const currentUrl = `${baseUrl}${resolvedUrl}`;
```

`getBaseUrl` is an helper function that return the base url of our current nextjs app.

Answer (score 0):

The redirection you are doing on the getServerSideProps is done in the server so no dom info can be accessed on that level. **You have tu pass the path info to the server in a cookie or something like that.**

Anyway, if im not mistaken, you redirect to SSO when you try to load a page and the auth fails. This auth happens on getServerSideProps so you can hardcode the SSO redirection url because you call a different getServerSideProps everytime you go to a new page.