# Where is from context object coming from to a getServerSideProps as a parameter?

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, i18next

I need to know this bcs i want to modify locale that coming from context on my own. But i dont know how this locale inside of context are setting.

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async context => {
    const { locale, req, res } = context;
```

Comment: That's handled internally by Next.js. Why do you want to modify the locale?

Comment: @juliomalves Hi. Bcs i need to build the route by myself. OUr locales are not static they're from API. Idea is I detect users locale(ip or browser preference) and compare to locales from API and set one if my API support it or just set default

Comment: If you're doing the locale detection and routing yourself then you need a custom implementation. Check what you need to check them return the dynamic locale value from `getServerSideProps`.

Comment: @juliomalves I've already have some logic for handling this. Just don't know how to get URL by which user came on my website to detect locale and see if it suits user and change it if not. If you could know how to get url  on server-side so i can reroute user not on client side

Comment: You can use `resolvedUrl` from the context object for that purpose. See [getServerSideProps access current browser url](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65617939/1870780).

Comment: @juliomalves I appreciate it) One more thing. How can i replace or add my locale to that resolvedUrl? is there any chance to doit server side?

Comment: You can use a redirect from the server-side using `redirect` in `getServerSideProps` return object. See https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-server-side-props#redirect.

Comment: @juliomalves if i redicrect through destination like this `${locale}${resolvedurl}. I still get 'domain/page/locale/resolvedUrl' . Any chance to get rid of page query that come after domain. So my locale is gonna be first after domain?

Comment: Use `/${locale}${resolvedurl}` instead for the redirect path (with forward slash at the beginning).

Comment: @juliomalves for some reason i get an error in the browser that i have to many redirects. Looks like it redirect all the time

Comment: You might want to check the `resolvedUrl` you get before redirecting. You should only redirect if the current URL doesn't fit your expected behaviour.

Comment: Is there any chance that you know how to exclude en locale from main page ('/') but on other pages keep it? It would be a lifasaver. In next config en is a default language. But i can change it if solution requires it@juliomalves